# onActivityResult inside Fragment never called

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-camera, onactivityresult

I have hosted activity (HomeActivty) that load fragments. My problem is whenever i click on captureimage button inside Fragment then camera started successfully but onActivityResult method is not triggered and it return null and crashed.

```
Here is my Fragemt class code:
    private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
    
            Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_SCREEN_ORIENTATION, 
            ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    
    
            if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getActivity().getPackageManager()) != null) {
                // Create the File where the photo should go
                File photoFile = null;
                try {
                    photoFile = createImageFile();
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                    // Error occurred while creating the File
                }
                if (photoFile != null) {
                    photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getActivity(),
                            BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider",
                            photoFile);
    
                    mPhotoFile = photoFile;
    
                    takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
                    startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO);
    
                }
            }
        }
```

onActivityResult Method:

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO) {
                try {
                    mPhotoFile = mCompressor.compressToFile(mPhotoFile);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                String filePath = mPhotoFile.getPath();
                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);
                int w = bitmap.getWidth();
                int h = bitmap.getHeight();
                if(w>h){
                    takepicture.setImageBitmap(RotateBitmap(bitmap,90));
                }else {
                    Glide.with(getActivity()).load(mPhotoFile).apply(new RequestOptions().centerCrop().placeholder(R.drawable.takepicture)).into(takepicture);
                }

            } else if (requestCode == REQUEST_GALLERY_PHOTO) {
                Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                try {
                    mPhotoFile = mCompressor.compressToFile(new File(getRealPathFromUri(selectedImage)));
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                String filePath = mPhotoFile.getPath();
                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);
                int w = bitmap.getWidth();
                int h = bitmap.getHeight();
                if(w>h){
                    takepicture.setImageBitmap(RotateBitmap(bitmap,90));
                }else {
                    Glide.with(getActivity()).load(mPhotoFile).apply(new RequestOptions().centerCrop().placeholder(R.drawable.takepicture)).into(takepicture);
                }


            }
        }
    }
```

This onActivityResult methoid is not called what can I do plz help me guyz.

Comment: What is making your app crash if `onActivityResult` is not called? Share the crash log.

Comment: nothing shown in the log related to this issue

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are also overriding **onActivityResult()** in your `HomeActivity` class. Thus make sure it also calls `super.onActivityResult()` to handover the unhandled result codes to children components like Fragment.

Comment: yes i'm overriding 'onActivityResult() and also calls super.onActivityResult() inside HomeActivity but the problem is still occur..would u plz share some piece of code.

Comment: can you  please share a part of HomeActivity code too

Comment: "@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_location_share);
        fragment.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        
    }"

Comment: it looks insignificant. Can you please remove this override at all in your HomeActivity?

Comment: still same problem

Comment: the same code i implemented in activity it works fine

Comment: now it's hard to debug or help without further investigating through logcat...

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try running the camera in a separate activity, let's say CameraActivity.
There, start the camera, get the result at the end and call finish.
In HomeActivity already catch onActivityResult